# How do I fix the width of the canvas in android

Tags: android

I am building a game for which the displayed level number comes from level.txt. However I am not unable to get the right width for the level number to be displayed on screen. The following block of code shows the code for level number :

```
 private void drawLevelNumber(Canvas canvas)
    {
      int y = 433;
      int x;
      int level = mLevelManager.getLevelIndex() + 1;
      if (level < 10) {
        x = 185;
        mFont.paintChar(Character.forDigit(level, 10), x, y, canvas,
                        mDisplayScale, mDisplayDX, mDisplayDY);
      } else if (level < 100) {
        x = 178;
        x += mFont.paintChar(Character.forDigit(level / 10, 10), x, y, canvas,
                             mDisplayScale, mDisplayDX, mDisplayDY);
        mFont.paintChar(Character.forDigit(level % 10, 10), x, y, canvas,
                        mDisplayScale, mDisplayDX, mDisplayDY);
      } else {
        x = 173;
        x += mFont.paintChar(Character.forDigit(level / 100, 10), x, y, canvas,
                             mDisplayScale, mDisplayDX, mDisplayDY);
        level -= 100 * (level / 100);
        x += mFont.paintChar(Character.forDigit(level / 10, 10), x, y, canvas,
                             mDisplayScale, mDisplayDX, mDisplayDY);
        mFont.paintChar(Character.forDigit(level % 10, 10), x, y, canvas,
                        mDisplayScale, mDisplayDX, mDisplayDY);
      }
    }
```

Any idea how I can fix the width of the displayed level number for the same?

Thanks!
Justin

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide more context. What exactly is going wrong? (A picture would help!) What are the various variables (`mFont`, `mDisplayScale`, etc.)? What does `paintChar` do? Where did the "magic numbers" (185, 178, 173) come from? Are you using Android's text painting APIs or are you rendering your own graphics for each digit? Where's the code that actually does the rendering?

Comment: I am testing the open source project frozen bubble, you can check it there for reference under GameView :https://github.com/robinst/frozen-bubble-android